# Install PHPUnit and Pear correctly on OSX Leopard

Tags: php, macos, phpunit, pear

I've installed pear using this guide http://t-machine.org/index.php/2008/12/28/how-to-install-pear-on-os-x-105/

In **/etc/php.ini** my **include_path = ".:/usr/local/PEAR"**

PHPUnit is installed under **/usr/local/PEAR/PHPUnit** using **sudo pear install phpunit/PHPUnit**(I get an error otherwise)

Yet when I try execute phpunit I'm getting this error

```
Warning: require_once(PHPUnit/Util/Filter.php): failed to open stream: Not a directory in /usr/local/bin/phpunit on line 44

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Util/Filter.php' (include_path='.:') in /usr/local/bin/phpunit on line 44
```

I'm just wondering has anyone got an idea of what the problem is or a complete(and correct guide) on installing pear osx.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a quick guess, that could be wrong, but perhaps you may need to add a trailing slash to the path like this: `include_path = ".:/usr/local/PEAR/"`

Edit: somehow /usr/local/PEAR is *not* in your include path as `(include_path='.:')` in your error message shows.

Answer (score 4):

Solved the problem I had a stupid ; before the include_path statement!

I am aware I'm an idiot, many thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're like me and none of these solutions were quite right, I'll share my solution. For some reason of which I lack the current knowledge to understand, on my Mac config, PHPUnit was reading the php.ini located in /etc/php.ini rather than the php.ini I thought it was reading located in /Applications/MAMP/conf/php5/php.ini.

In the former, my path was /usr/share/pear. In the latter, it was usr/local/pear. Changing the former file to match the latter and rerunning phpunit resulted in

```
phpunit StackTest.php 
PHPUnit 3.4.5 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 3.50Mb

OK (1 test, 5 assertions)
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: I also had this issue using MAMP - it turned out that at the top of /usr/bin/phpunit the !# referred to an older version of php

Answer (score 0):

Try changing that to be:

```
require_once("../../PHPUnit/Util/Filter.php");
```

If you look at the error, it shows that you are trying to access the wrong directory.